# how to use XBMC with frame buffer?

Tags: graphics, framebuffer, xbmc

We have cross-compiled XBMC for a Set-top-Box, board with Intel graphics card.
When I run XBMC , we are getting the following errors:

10:20:09 T:3053991728 M:527937536 ERROR: CXRandR::Query - unable to open xrandr xml
10:20:09 T:3053991728 M:527945728 NOTICE: Setup SDL
10:20:09 T:3053991728 M:529735680 FATAL: XBAppEx: Unable to initialize SDL: DirectFBCreate: Initialization error!

I do have all the related libraries and have linked the same thru LD_LIBRARY_PATH , Does any one know how to configure XBMC to use the FrameBuffers.

Any quick help in this regard is of great help.

Thanks in advance,